# checking a time in the future in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, row

I have two tables

1) dayplanner: day split in 5 minute intervals Values=00:00:00,00:05:00,00:10:00 ...23:55:00
2) reservations: name, start and finish Values=[john,12:00:00,12:30:00],[bob,14:00:00,14:45:00],etc

This query

SELECT d.dayplanner_time, IF(d.dayplanner_time = a.reservations_starttime,'true','false') AS reserved,IF(a.reservations_start is null, false, true) AS inbetween
      FROM dayplanner d 
      LEFT JOIN reservations a 
      ON (d.day_time >= a.reservations_start AND d.dayplanner_time <= a.reservations_finish) WHERE d.dayplanner_time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '18:00:00';

What i want is a check row with true/false if a startime is 15 minutes before start. This is because a reservation should not be shorter then this. I made a function but it doesn't work

```
function timeinterval($var1,$var2){
$datetime1=strtotime('$var1');
$datetime2=strtotime('$var2');
$interval=abs($datetime2-$datetime1);
$minutes=round($interval/60);
if($minutes < 15){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'false';
}
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

use [SQL DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) with the "Minutes" option to get the time difference. then you can check the value of that column to see if it is within 15 minutes.  I was unsure if you wanted to do your check within the query itself or in post-processing so i didnt give an exact example

Comment: What i`m trying to do is check per time value
(from the dayplanner table) if it`s located before the starttime of the reservation. So if a time variable is outside the 15 minute range it says false. I`m using Mysql by the way. I`ll look if there is some similar function in mysql. Can i place an eventual statement behind the select?

Comment: can you clarify this ?  "What i want is a check row with true/false if a startime is 15 minutes before start. This is because a reservation should not be shorter then this."  .  What 'starttime' needs to be before what 'start' ?  I didn't really understand how the dayplanner table fit into this question since it is just a static list of times.  Are we trying to check an existing reservation, or is this when trying to submit a new reservation and to check if it is a valid time ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. The dayplanner table is static and reservations are linked with it via a join. If someone wants to plan a meeting it should not be for 5 min but a minimal of 15. If I can determine the value before a reservation is <= 15 min it wil be blocked. I`m fairly new a this so my appolagies if it`s not very coherent.

Comment: This would really not have anything to do with your database then because this would either be checked on the front end (in javascript) or in php code on backend before the query is run because you dont want to run the query if the submission is invalid.  Take a look at the second answer by TunaMaxx to see if it fixes your time comparison function

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your function does not work because it is trying to run `strtotime()` on literal strings '$var1' and '$var2' not the values of the arguments $var1 and $var2 passed in to the function. Second, you should be returning the boolean values from your function, not the string equivalents.

Try this instead:

```
function timeinterval($var1, $var2)
{
    $datetime1 = strtotime($var1);
    $datetime2 = strtotime($var2);
    $interval  = abs($datetime2 - $datetime1);
    $minutes   = round($interval/60);

    return $minutes < 15; // returns boolean true or false depending on outcome
}
```

Comment: Thanx. I tried it but it gives only '1' in the first 15 min inside the reservation and the rest is 0. What I want is before the reservation so I can block it